# SOAPAction header value must be enclosed in double-quotes through WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm sending a request to a server with "SOAPAction urn:abcd", when I send it directly to the server through SOAP UI I'm able to get the output. but when I send using WSO2 ESB I'm getting

```html
<SOAP:Envelope SOAP:encodingStyle="urn:asdf" xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP:Body>
      <SOAP:Fault>
         <faultcode>SOAP:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Client Error</faultstring>
         <detail xmlns="asdf">
            <message>SOAPAction header value must be enclosed in double-quotes</message>
            <errortype>HTTPHeaderError</errortype>
         </detail>
      </SOAP:Fault>
   </SOAP:Body>
</SOAP:Envelope>
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Can you attach your proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Just give SOAPAction header with two double quotes

e.g.: ""urn:getQuote""